# Asp.net Membership provider remove application access

Tags: asp.net, security, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

We are using asp.net Membership provider, we have around 40 applications where the users, roles everything configured through Membership provider.  Now one of the requirement that we have is to disable access to some applications if user haven't logged a application since 30 days.  We should not touch the application just membership provider manipulation is what we can do.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the database access, you can actually try to disable the login using a database script so the change can be applied without you touching the application at all.

For example, you can first query the **membership** table, like `aspnet_Membership`, and find the records where the **last login date** is great than and equal to 30 days (`datediff(day, lastlogindate, getdate()) >= 30`), then set the field `IsLockedOut = 1` on those records.

Hopefully this helps.